# Document is undefined when trying to set a cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie, with the users password in it. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
  User.findOne({ 'credentials.username': gusername }, function(err, user){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (user) {
var gottenpassword = user.credentials.password;
if (gpassword==gottenpassword) {

//Problem right here!!

document.cookie="password="+gpassword+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

// Problem ^^^^

res.redirect('/');

 } else {
    res.render('login',{logerr:'the password is wrong!'});
}
} else {
res.render('login',{logerr:'user does not exist!'});
  }

});
```

When I execute the code and login successfully, it should redirect to the home page and create that cookie, but instead the app crashes and logs this to the console:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/index.js:126:9)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I was thinking maybe it redirects too fast to the home page, instead of allowing the document to load and create the cookie? Not sure. Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: there is no document on server ... it's part of the window object in browser

Comment: @charlietfl I'm still fairly new to JS. Mind giving a hint on how I should create the cookie? Should I create a function to make the cookie on a page after I redirect?

Comment: do a google search ... `node cookie`